# Inherited interface cannot access extended method when DI

Tags: asp.net, generics, dependency-injection

This is my Author ApiControler

```
public class AuthorController : BaseEntityWebApiProvider<Author, IAuthorLogicProvider>
{
    #region [ CTor ]
    public AuthorController(ILogger<BaseEntityWebApiProvider<Author, IAuthorLogicProvider>> logger, 
                            IAuthorLogicProvider logicProvider) : base(logger, logicProvider) {
    }
    #endregion

    #region [ Methods -  ]
    [HttpGet(nameof(MethodUrl.GetListByBookId) + "/{BookId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetListByBookIdAsync(string bookId) {
        try {
             // cannnot access the method
            var result = await this._logicProvider.GetListByBookIdAsync(bookId);

            if (result == null || result.Count() <= 0) {
                return NotFound("Empty");
            }

            return Ok(result);
        } catch (ArgumentNullException ex) {
            this._logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            return BadRequest();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            this._logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

this is my Base ApiController

```
[ApiController]
[Route("Api/V1/[controller]")]
public abstract class BaseEntityWebApiProvider<TEntity, TLogicProvider> : ControllerBase
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
    where TLogicProvider : IBaseEntityLogicProvider<TEntity> 
{
    #region [ Fields ]
    protected readonly ILogger<BaseEntityWebApiProvider<TEntity, TLogicProvider>> _logger;
    protected readonly IBaseEntityLogicProvider<TEntity> _logicProvider;
    #endregion

    #region [ CTor ]
    public BaseEntityWebApiProvider(ILogger<BaseEntityWebApiProvider<TEntity, TLogicProvider>> logger,
        TLogicProvider logicProvider) {

        this._logger = logger;
        this._logicProvider = logicProvider;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

this is my Author Interface

```
public interface IAuthorLogicProvider : IBaseEntityLogicProvider<Author>
{
    #region [ Methods - List ]
    Task<IEnumerable<Author>> GetListByBookIdAsync(string bookId);
    #endregion
}
```

this is my Base Interface

```
public interface IBaseEntityLogicProvider<TEntity> : IBaseEntityDataProvider<TEntity>
    where TEntity : BaseEntity
{
}
```

I think that the BaseEntityWebApiProvider only takes the IBaseEntityLogicProvider
It does not take the IAuthorLogicProvider as an input, therefore I cannot access the GetListByBookIdAsync(bookId) method.

Is there any way to work around this?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Make it a member of your class. Don’t access it through the parent class

Comment: _logicProvider is of type IBaseEntityLogicProvider<TEntity>, your method is just not defined in this interface, so how can you call it? You need to use a filed of type IAuthorLogicProvider or type that implements this interface. Imagine, you have a variable of type "Object" and you want to get it's property "Length" just becuase String defines it and inherites from Object. Sensless, right? Becuase u can't guarantee your variable is of type String. And your situation is exactly the same.